Boost integer_modulus Usage
Boost documentation mentions the integer_modulus function.
template <class Integer1, class Integer2>
Integer2 integer_modulus(const Integer1& x, Integer2 val);

I've found that it resides in boost/multiprecision/integer.hpp in the boost::multiprecision namespace. However, I cannot figure out how to make it work. I tried different compilers but got the same no matching and possible candidates errors at the compilation stage. The example is here.
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/integer.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;
using bigint_t = mp::int256_t;

int main() {
  bigint_t a = -28;
  bigint_t b = 10;
  bigint_t c = mp::integer_modulus(a, b);
  std::cout << (a % b) << std::endl;
  std::cout << c << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

Errors:
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:11:35: error: no matching function for call to 'integer_modulus(bigint_t&, bigint_t&)'
   11 |   bigint_t c = mp::integer_modulus(a, b);
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_85_0/boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp:20,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_85_0/boost/multiprecision/integer.hpp:11,
                 from <source>:2:
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_85_0/boost/multiprecision/detail/integer_ops.hpp:155:1: note: candidate: 'template<class Backend, boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option ExpressionTemplates, class Integer> constexpr typename std::enable_if<(boost::multiprecision::detail::is_integral<I>::value && (boost::multiprecision::number_category<Num>::value == boost::multiprecision::number_kind_integer)), Integer>::type boost::multiprecision::integer_modulus(const number<Backend, ExpressionTemplates>&, Integer)'
  155 | integer_modulus(const number<Backend, ExpressionTemplates>& x, Integer val)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_85_0/boost/multiprecision/detail/integer_ops.hpp:155:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_85_0/boost/multiprecision/detail/integer_ops.hpp: In substitution of 'template<class Backend, boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option ExpressionTemplates, class Integer> constexpr typename std::enable_if<(boost::multiprecision::detail::is_integral<I>::value && (boost::multiprecision::number_category<Num>::value == boost::multiprecision::number_kind_integer)), Integer>::type boost::multiprecision::integer_modulus(const number<Backend, ExpressionTemplates>&, Integer) [with Backend = boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<256, 256, boost::multiprecision::signed_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::unchecked, void>; boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option ExpressionTemplates = boost::multiprecision::et_off; Integer = boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<256, 256, boost::multiprecision::signed_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::unchecked, void> >]':
<source>:11:35:   required from here
   11 |   bigint_t c = mp::integer_modulus(a, b);
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_85_0/boost/multiprecision/detail/integer_ops.hpp:155:1: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<256, 256, boost::multiprecision::signed_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::unchecked, void> > >'
  155 | integer_modulus(const number<Backend, ExpressionTemplates>& x, Integer val)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_85_0/boost/multiprecision/detail/integer_ops.hpp:163:1: note: candidate: 'template<class tag, class A1, class A2, class A3, class A4, class Integer> constexpr typename std::enable_if<(boost::multiprecision::detail::is_integral<I>::value && (boost::multiprecision::number_category<typename boost::multiprecision::detail::expression<tag, Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4>::result_type>::value == boost::multiprecision::number_kind_integer)), Integer>::type boost::multiprecision::integer_modulus(const detail::expression<tag, Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4>&, Integer)'
  163 | integer_modulus(const multiprecision::detail::expression<tag, A1, A2, A3, A4>& x, Integer val)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_85_0/boost/multiprecision/detail/integer_ops.hpp:163:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:11:35: note:   'bigint_t' {aka 'boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<256, 256, boost::multiprecision::signed_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::unchecked, void> >'} is not derived from 'const boost::multiprecision::detail::expression<tag, Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4>'
   11 |   bigint_t c = mp::integer_modulus(a, b);
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_85_0/boost/multiprecision/integer.hpp:46:179: note: candidate: 'template<class I1, class I2> constexpr typename std::enable_if<(boost::multiprecision::detail::is_integral<T>::value && boost::multiprecision::detail::is_integral<Arithmetic>::value), I2>::type boost::multiprecision::integer_modulus(const I1&, I2)'
   46 | inline BOOST_MP_CXX14_CONSTEXPR typename std::enable_if<boost::multiprecision::detail::is_integral<I1>::value && boost::multiprecision::detail::is_integral<I2>::value, I2>::type integer_modulus(const I1& x, I2 val)
      |                                                                                                                                                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_85_0/boost/multiprecision/integer.hpp:46:179: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_85_0/boost/multiprecision/integer.hpp: In substitution of 'template<class I1, class I2> constexpr typename std::enable_if<(boost::multiprecision::detail::is_integral<T>::value && boost::multiprecision::detail::is_integral<Arithmetic>::value), I2>::type boost::multiprecision::integer_modulus(const I1&, I2) [with I1 = boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<256, 256, boost::multiprecision::signed_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::unchecked, void> >; I2 = boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<256, 256, boost::multiprecision::signed_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::unchecked, void> >]':
<source>:11:35:   required from here
   11 |   bigint_t c = mp::integer_modulus(a, b);
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_85_0/boost/multiprecision/integer.hpp:46:179: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<256, 256, boost::multiprecision::signed_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::unchecked, void> > >'
   46 | inline BOOST_MP_CXX14_CONSTEXPR typename std::enable_if<boost::multiprecision::detail::is_integral<I1>::value && boost::multiprecision::detail::is_integral<I2>::value, I2>::type integer_modulus(const I1& x, I2 val)
      |                                                                                                                                                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:11:35: error: no matching function for call to 'integer_modulus(bigint_t&, bigint_t&)'
   11 |   bigint_t c = mp::integer_modulus(a, b);
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_85_0/boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp:20,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_85_0/boost/multiprecision/integer.hpp:11,
                 from <source>:2:
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_85_0/boost/multiprecision/detail/integer_ops.hpp:155:1: note: candidate: 'template<class Backend, boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option ExpressionTemplates, class Integer> constexpr typename std::enable_if<(boost::multiprecision::detail::is_integral<I>::value && (boost::multiprecision::number_category<Num>::value == boost::multiprecision::number_kind_integer)), Integer>::type boost::multiprecision::integer_modulus(const number<Backend, ExpressionTemplates>&, Integer)'
  155 | integer_modulus(const number<Backend, ExpressionTemplates>& x, Integer val)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_85_0/boost/multiprecision/detail/integer_ops.hpp:155:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_85_0/boost/multiprecision/detail/integer_ops.hpp: In substitution of 'template<class Backend, boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option ExpressionTemplates, class Integer> constexpr typename std::enable_if<(boost::multiprecision::detail::is_integral<I>::value && (boost::multiprecision::number_category<Num>::value == boost::multiprecision::number_kind_integer)), Integer>::type boost::multiprecision::integer_modulus(const number<Backend, ExpressionTemplates>&, Integer) [with Backend = boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<256, 256, boost::multiprecision::signed_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::unchecked, void>; boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option ExpressionTemplates = boost::multiprecision::et_off; Integer = boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<256, 256, boost::multiprecision::signed_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::unchecked, void> >]':
<source>:11:35:   required from here
   11 |   bigint_t c = mp::integer_modulus(a, b);
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_85_0/boost/multiprecision/detail/integer_ops.hpp:155:1: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<256, 256, boost::multiprecision::signed_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::unchecked, void> > >'
  155 | integer_modulus(const number<Backend, ExpressionTemplates>& x, Integer val)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_85_0/boost/multiprecision/detail/integer_ops.hpp:163:1: note: candidate: 'template<class tag, class A1, class A2, class A3, class A4, class Integer> constexpr typename std::enable_if<(boost::multiprecision::detail::is_integral<I>::value && (boost::multiprecision::number_category<typename boost::multiprecision::detail::expression<tag, Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4>::result_type>::value == boost::multiprecision::number_kind_integer)), Integer>::type boost::multiprecision::integer_modulus(const detail::expression<tag, Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4>&, Integer)'
  163 | integer_modulus(const multiprecision::detail::expression<tag, A1, A2, A3, A4>& x, Integer val)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_85_0/boost/multiprecision/detail/integer_ops.hpp:163:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:11:35: note:   'bigint_t' {aka 'boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<256, 256, boost::multiprecision::signed_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::unchecked, void> >'} is not derived from 'const boost::multiprecision::detail::expression<tag, Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4>'
   11 |   bigint_t c = mp::integer_modulus(a, b);
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_85_0/boost/multiprecision/integer.hpp:46:179: note: candidate: 'template<class I1, class I2> constexpr typename std::enable_if<(boost::multiprecision::detail::is_integral<T>::value && boost::multiprecision::detail::is_integral<Arithmetic>::value), I2>::type boost::multiprecision::integer_modulus(const I1&, I2)'
   46 | inline BOOST_MP_CXX14_CONSTEXPR typename std::enable_if<boost::multiprecision::detail::is_integral<I1>::value && boost::multiprecision::detail::is_integral<I2>::value, I2>::type integer_modulus(const I1& x, I2 val)
      |                                                                                                                                                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_85_0/boost/multiprecision/integer.hpp:46:179: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_85_0/boost/multiprecision/integer.hpp: In substitution of 'template<class I1, class I2> constexpr typename std::enable_if<(boost::multiprecision::detail::is_integral<T>::value && boost::multiprecision::detail::is_integral<Arithmetic>::value), I2>::type boost::multiprecision::integer_modulus(const I1&, I2) [with I1 = boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<256, 256, boost::multiprecision::signed_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::unchecked, void> >; I2 = boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<256, 256, boost::multiprecision::signed_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::unchecked, void> >]':
<source>:11:35:   required from here
   11 |   bigint_t c = mp::integer_modulus(a, b);
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_85_0/boost/multiprecision/integer.hpp:46:179: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<256, 256, boost::multiprecision::signed_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::unchecked, void> > >'
   46 | inline BOOST_MP_CXX14_CONSTEXPR typename std::enable_if<boost::multiprecision::detail::is_integral<I1>::value && boost::multiprecision::detail::is_integral<I2>::value, I2>::type integer_modulus(const I1& x, I2 val)
      |                                                                                                                                                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Execution build compiler returned: 1

So, the question is: How to make it work?

Which errors at the compilation stage do you get? This should be embedded in the question.

Added the errors. I thought it's enough to provide a link to Godbolt, since the error output is quite large.

It was not enough. When other users try to search similar errors, how they would find this question on SO?

Really. I agree on that.

You missed a key point in the documentation.  In your link the key point is that the functions

are overloaded for the fundamental (built-in) integer types

And indeed if you look at the source code the function is defined as
template <class I1, class I2>
typename enable_if_c<is_integral<I1>::value && is_integral<I2>::value, I2>::type integer_modulus(const I1& x, I2 val)
{
   return static_cast<I2>(x % val);
}

And as you can see it is constrained to types where is_integral<Type> is true.

Oh! Thank you for pointing that out! Looks like I didn't understand that correctly because I used bit_set and msb functions and they worked flawlessly. Thought that integer_modulus should work too.
